# Webcam.js back camera moibile view not able to switch over?

Tags: angularjs, webcam.js

I am using webcam.js for capturing images from my application using web camera.
But in mobile browsers i am not able to capture images using back camera Only i can able to capture images in front camera.

So can you please give me some suggestions or alternative solutions this issue.

I refered this link for my application integration same code  i am using.

https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/qww6g0a6/

```
<webcam channel="channel" 
        on-streaming="onSuccess()" 
        on-error="onError(err)" 
        on-stream="onStream(stream)"></webcam>
    <button ng-click="makeSnapshot()">take
```